# Clean way for struct to reassign multiple fields using an associated function?

Tags: rust

Consider this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=3ea13de5b58d924e2c217cc30c8e08d1) example:

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
struct Things {
    zero: usize,
    one: usize,
    ...
    nine: usize,
}

fn do_fancy_calculation() -> (usize, usize, usize, usize, usize) {
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
}

impl Things {
    fn renew(&mut self) {
        // does not work:
        // let self {one, two, five, seven, eight} = do_fancy_calculation();

        //
        let (one, two, five, seven, eight) = do_fancy_calculation();
        self.one = one;
        self.two = two;
        self.five = five;
        self.seven = seven;
        self.eight = eight;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let (zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine) =
        (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    let mut things = Things {
        zero,
        ...
        nine,
    };

    things.renew();

    println!("{}", things.one);
}
```

How can I nicely assign to `one, two, five, seven, eight`, without resorting to multiple `self.x = y;` type statements?

I call the toy associated function `renew` because in my actual use case, the struct represents the state of something, and I need to refresh/renew/recreate some variables to represent changes in state. Am I going about solving my use case the wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update a subset of the fields of `self` using assignment:

```
*self = Self { one, two, five, seven, eight, ..*self };
```

This updates the named fields with the matching local variables, and leaves the remaining fields unchanged.  I'm not sure, though, whether this is more readable than what you have.

I would also consider a few other options.  The return type of `do_fancy_calculation()` doesn't really convey much meaning – maybe return a `struct` instead?  If the function is always used to update the state of `Thing`s, you could make it an associated function that directly updates `Thing`, so you wouldn't need to merge the return values into `Thing` anymore.